# Question of pole and zeros of symmetric or exterior global $L$-function of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $\pi$ be a unitary cuspidal representation of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})$.

It is written is some paper that using the results towards the generalized Ramanujan conjecture in the paper "On the generalized Ramanujan conjecture for GL(n)" by Luo, Rudnick and Sarnak  (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247040108_On_the_generalized_Ramanujan_conjecture_for_GL), one can prove that $L(s,\pi,\mathrm{Sym}^2)$ and $L(s,\pi,\bigwedge^2)$ are nonzero for $Re(s) \ge 2$. But I don't know why it does.

I would appreciate if you let me know this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, let $F$ be a number field, and assume that $\pi$ is a cuspidal automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{A}_F)$ with trivial conductor.  [Miller and Schmid](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2012-25-02/S0894-0347-2011-00719-4/home.html) proved that $L(s,\pi;\bigwedge^2)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\}$.  [Takeda](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-163/issue-1/The-twisted-symmetric-square-L-function-of-GLr/10.1215/00127094-2405497.short) proved that $L(s,\pi;\mathrm{Sym}^2)$ is holomorphic on $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1-\frac{1}{n}$ except for a possible pole at $s=1$.  (There might be other references to establish the holomorphy in the half-plane $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$, but these sources came to mind first.)  We have the factorization

$L(s,\pi\times\pi) = L(s,\pi;\mathrm{Sym}^2) L(s,\pi;\bigwedge^2).$

[Jacquet, Piatetski-Shapiro, and Shalika](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374264) proved (among many other things) that $L(s,\pi\times\pi)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\}$.  They also proved that the Euler product that defines $L(s,\pi\times\pi)$ converges absolutely for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$.  It follows that $L(s,\pi\times\pi)$ does not vanish in this region.  We now conclude that $L(s,\pi;\mathrm{Sym}^2)$ and $L(s,\pi;\bigwedge^2)$ are both holomorphic and non-vanishing for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$.  More generally, in the region $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1-1/n$ (and away from a possible pole at $s=1$), $L(s,\pi;\mathrm{Sym}^2)$ and $L(s,\pi;\bigwedge^2)$ are non-vanishing in whatever zero-free region is available for $L(s,\pi\times\pi)$.  For arbitrary $\pi$, the best such zero-free region is due to [Brumley](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/%7Ebrumley/Research_files/HC-Schwartz.pdf) (see the appendix).

If the conductor of $\pi$ is nontrivial, then everything needs to first be expressed in terms of partial $L$-functions, omitting the Euler factors at the places $v$ at which $\pi_v$ ramifies.  The holomorphy of these Euler factors can be deduced from bounds of Luo--Rudnick--Sarnak type, but for the *ramified* places, which they do not address.  For variants of the Luo--Rudnick--Sarnak progress towards the generalized Ramanujan conjecture at all places (not just the unramified ones), see [Müller and Speh](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00039-004-0452-0) (Section 3) or [Blomer and Brumley](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/nonvanishing-of-lfunctions-the-ramanujan-conjecture-and-families-of-hecke-characters/90ABA4CD3FEBF0C06BA208EC7036AF3D).

(For future posts:  "It is written is some paper..." is far too vague.)

Comment: Oh I am really grateful to your very kind answer! It helped me really a lot! Thank you also for the mentioning the references. I will check it. Again, I thank you!